# Templated enum types based on template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I was wondering how to do this:
Say I have a class A, with enum B inside it

```
class A {

enum B {

};

};
```

And I'd like to create a function that takes A as a template and then assumes A has an enum B type and receives its val as a parameter? I tried something like:

```
template<typename T>
static void Foo(T t, T::B b) {}
```

But that didn't work.. anyone has an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Would you have to ensure `T` extends `A`?

Comment: Nope, just assume the enum is there

Comment: Would it not be more correct using A::B ?

Comment: @user2672165 This is a template. (see: `template<typename T>`)

Comment: @Rapptz: you are correct. I should read question at least twice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that `T::B` is a type, because it is a dependent name, and is assumed to be a non-type by default.

```
template<typename T>
static void Foo(T t, typename T::B b) {}
//                   ^^^^^^^^
```

You should also make the enum public. This code sample works:

```
class A {
 public:
  enum B {x, y, z};
};

template<typename T>
static void Foo(T t, typename T::B b) {}

int main()
{
  Foo(A(), A::x); // OK
}
```

For an in-depth explanation, see [*Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords):

Answer (score 4):

you have to use typename keyword to make it work:

```
static void Foo(T t, typename T::B b) {}
                        ^
```

and `enum B` has to be public.

`typename` keyword it is used for specifying that a dependent name in a template definition or declaration is a type. It is synonym for a `class` in template parameters.

C++ standard states:

> A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is
>   dependent on a template-parameter is assumed not to name a type unless
>   the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified
>   by the keyword typename.

so unless you state explicitly `typename T::B b`, compiler will assume `T::B b` is value type not a type name.

To summarise:

```
class A {
 public:
  enum B {enum1, enum2};
};

template<typename T>
static void Foo(T t, typename T::B b) {}

int main()
{
  A a;
  Foo(a, a::enum1); 
}
```

[typename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typename)